# Alljoyn Studio Watcher class not generated

Tags: alljoyn, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I'm developing a consumer app using Alljoyn runtime libraries generated using a interface XML, for some reason visual studio doesn't create the watcher class using the Alljoyn Studio, Ive got producer and consumer but no watcher. Is there a problem with my interface xml (to check I used different XMLs but this is not working for me), how do I check for devices on the d-bus, is there another way? if not can someone please help me how to fix this problem, to generate the watcher class?

P.S. I'm using VS Enterprise 2015 with updates on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some changes made to AllJoyn Studio, so you can't get watcher class by visual studio. You can use [AllJoynBusAttachment.GetWatcher()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt739455.aspx) instead.

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e78796f3-db12-4013-ae7f-42c4db6e3d51/alljoyn-studio-watcher-class-not-generated?forum=WindowsIoT) is the original answer.